# TypeScript does not see any modules when compiling

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

For some reason, when compiling the nestJs project, such errors began to appear. This does not apply to any particular library, but to almost all ts links.

```
node_modules/axios/index.d.ts:108:12 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AbortSignal'.

108   signal?: AbortSignal;
               ~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/axios/index.d.ts:126:49 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Omit'.

95     get sqljsManager(): SqljsEntityManager;
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/typeorm/connection/ConnectionOptionsReader.d.ts:55:19 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

55     protected get baseFilePath(): string;
```

Package.json - https://pastebin.com/CFeMenVD
tsconfig.json - https://pastebin.com/9y5yBFZz

I tried:

1. reinstall node + ts
2. install @type/* manually
3. remove node_modules

When changing version of nodejs, npm, rollback to previous package.json.
Nothing helps

UPD#1:
Adding "skipLibCheck": true, - doesn't solve issue
@types/node and "types": ["node"], - still same issue

Comment: just add `"skipLibCheck": true,` in your tsconfig file under `compilerOptions`

Comment: Micael, this not works :( same issues

Comment: add `"types": ["node"],` as well

Comment: and install `@types/node`, of course

Comment: @types/node - installed (did you seen my package.json?)
"types": ["node"], - still same issue